# Clarification $http service vs custom service in angular1.4

Tags: angularjs, service

I am taking two different classes on Udemy and started with angular2 so I understand ng2's service approach. Now I'm learning angular 1, can someone clarify angular1's $http service for me? Do I use it in a custom service? or is it the service that goes within a controller? Basically what's the best practice for a non crud $http GET of json

Comment: You can do either but I think most people would recommend that you use it in a custom service.

Comment: So do I inject the HTTP service object? all the custom service examples I see don't have dependency injection, they just look like normal functions

Comment: Yes, inject $http where you need to use it....service, controller or directive etc

Answer (score 2):

The common agreed upon best practice is to separate all your $http requests from your controllers in a service/factory.

This guide is great if you've got a good grasp on Javascript but are looking for some best practice suggestions for Angular 1.x:

https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#defer-controller-logic-to-services